# Spring framework - how to pass parameters in static factory method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Need to pass parameters in static factory method, adn want to create spring bean - how to o that, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving arguments into a factory method (via XML config) is described [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/48256-using-factory-beans-with-factory-method-parameters), the important thing would be (also see the documentation for [static factory methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method))...

```
public class DaoFactoryCreator {
    public static DaoFactory createDaoFactory(List daos) {
        ... this is the factory method, do something here and return it
    }
}

<bean id="daoFactory" class="com.javalobby.tnt.spring.DaoFactoryCreator" factory-method="createDaoFactory" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>
            <list>
                <ref bean="dao1"/>
                <ref bean="dao2"/>
                <ref bean="dao3"/>
            </list>
        </value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```